# How to get the exact dSYM file in crashlytics

Tags: ios

I am missing my dSYM file where i followed each step given in the document still missing those file.There were the option of uploading the zip dSYM file or drag drop it but it showed me wait and check the status afterwards.Even the debug symbol has been set to no.Can you please tell me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your project, go to Build settings and under Build Options, Debug Information Format add "DWARF with dSYM File".

[image]

Comment: stop debug mode ( [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] setDebugMode:YES]; ). See did you sent the last version and if the last version is with the last version of the provision profile.